# How to link to a specific time in a YouTube video

Tags: youtube, url

What is the format for a YouTube URL, to link to a specific time in the video? Something like

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze68s47-xO4<time code goes here>
```

Comment: http://youtu.be/Ze68s47-xO4?t=2m6s

Comment: You can also use #t=nnn where nnn is the seconds (only as many digits as you need).

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1. Provide the `t` variable as query parameter:

   ```
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze68s47-xO4&t=23
   ```

   for starting the video at 23s mark.
2. Provide `t` value as a URL hash location:

   ```
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze68s47-xO4#t=2m7s
   ```

   for starting the video from 127s mark.

Answer (score 1):

When you click "Share", it lets you enter the specific time and generates an URL with the `t` parameter, containing `Xs`, `XmYs`, or `XhYmZs`, e.g. `2m6s`.